# Subdomain - How to point 2 subdomains to the same folder - ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

We have 2 subdomains example https://dev.abc.net AND https://client1.abc.net/

The Source code (PHP files are at) is on https://dev.abc.net

We need the code to be there on dev but point the other subdomain as well to the same folder

The problem is:

Example this is Working: 
https://dev.abc.net/LoginSaaS.php

This is Not working:  https://client1.abc.net/LoginSaaS.php says 404 not found

What shall we do in the host file or htaccess or somewhere else?

Here is the file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName  dev.test.abc.net
#    Alias /pma/ /var/www/html/pma/
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhosl
    DocumentRoot /var/www/live-site-data/dev.test.abc.net

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/dev.2-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/dev.2-access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Are you using Apache? What does your `VirtualHost` configuration look like for the two subdomains?

Comment: @BobDole https://prnt.sc/nb2o74 here is the screenshot and yes I am using apache

Comment: You should have some files in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` for your virtualhost configuration that would define how it responds to specific sub domains. You should [check out this guide](https://www.ostechnix.com/configure-apache-virtual-hosts-ubuntu-part-1/) for some information on how to setup multiple domains (except in your case you would have the same DocumentRoot for both VirtualHosts).

Comment: @BobDole I updated the question with the file contents for /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ not sure what should I do here

Comment: @Christopher so ServerAlias should be client1.abc.net?

Comment: @Christopher ServerAlias helped thanks so much :) If you can post the answer and I will accept it.